# Why is declaration of two property restrictions at once involve the rdfs:subClassof and sometimes just a comma alone?

Tags: owl, rdfs, turtle-rdf

Two property restriction declarations with `rdfs:subClassOf` in between them:

[image]

Two property restriction with a comma in between:

[image]

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#object-lists

Comment: Thanks for the link @Stanslav, does this mean that the subject "express:List"  has two objects given by two restrictions separated by a comma. However in some cases, there is no comma but rather another rdfs:Subclassof tag. Can you please clarify this. Thanks

Comment: "Another `rdfs:SubClassOf`" is https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#predicate-lists. All these three are the same: 1. `:L rdfs:subClassOf :A . :L rdfs:subClassOf :B .`, 2. `:L rdfs:subClassOf :A ; rdfs:subClassOf :B .`, 3. `:L rdfs:subClassOf :A , :B`.

Comment: "Sometimes a list, sometimes another rdfs:subClassOf statement"

These are just details of the serialization, there is no semantic difference. The code creating the Turtle output is free to choose one or the other way of writing out the triples. The content of the ontology, after parsing, is identical.

Comment: comma between objects if same subject and predicate. Semicolon between predicate-object pairs if same subject. It doesn't matter what type the object is (here blank node short form). And yes, you could indeed always use the verbose form and write proper RDF triples. It's just syntactic sugar